# Using tree surgeon to adjoin POS to NN

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to work through some Tree objects and need to adjoin the "'s" possessive (POS) nodes to their respective nouns (NN).

I'm currently hoping the tsurgeon tools will do this, and they do indeed seem designed to the task. However, my errors are strange and non productive.

I'll try and set this up as best as possible with the context of the application and the output seen, a small test program has been written to figure out this use case, but I'm afraid even that is somewhat large and complex, os please excuse my setup.

```
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
//Pattern: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html
TregexPattern adjoinPOS = TregexPattern.compile("POS=pos , NN=noun");
TsurgeonPattern tsurgeon = Tsurgeon.parseOperation("adjoin pos@ noun");
for( CoreMap sentence : sentences ) {
   Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
   tree = Tsurgeon.processPattern(adjoinPOS, tsurgeon, tree);
   tree.pennPrint();
}
```

This, unfortunately, does nothing productive, instead I get a null pointer exception within stanford nlp:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.tsurgeon.AdjoinNode$Matcher.evaluate(AdjoinNode.java:49)
> at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.tsurgeon.TsurgeonPatternRoot$Matcher.evaluate(TsurgeonPatternRoot.java:63)
> at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.tsurgeon.Tsurgeon.processPattern(Tsurgeon.java:579)
> ```

```
at my.code.line of the processPattern call (yeah, I cleaned this up a little for brevity)
```

Let's assume that the sentence tree is:

> (ROOT (SBARQ (WHNP (WP What)) (SQ (VBZ is) (NP (NP (NP (DT the) (NN
>   cannonball) (POS 's)) (NN maximum) (NN altitude)) (PP (IN during) (NP
>   (NN flight))))) (. ?)))

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to use the tree surgeon to edit this tree?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use *adjoin* in this case because *adjoin* is used to combine a subtree in PTB format and a node from another tree.

I think what you want to do is something like that:

```
Tree t = Tree.valueOf("(ROOT (SBARQ (WHNP (WP What)) (SQ (VBZ is) (NP (NP (NP (DT the) (NN cannonball) (POS 's)) (NN maximum) (NN altitude)) (PP (IN during) (NP (NN flight))))) (. ?)))");
//Pattern: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html
TregexPattern adjoinPOS = TregexPattern.compile("(POS=postag < __=pos ) $- NN=noun");
TsurgeonPattern tsurgeon = Tsurgeon.parseOperation("[move pos >-1 noun] [delete postag]");
Tsurgeon.processPattern(adjoinPOS, tsurgeon, t);
```

This will move the clitic *'s* next to *cannonball* (the NN will then have two children) and delete the POS node.

Comment: The node is already in the correct position, immediately following the NN, perhaps I didn't make clear my intention in the question. I need to put the 's onto the end of the noun and not treat it as a separate token. This is for coreference chain processing later on. I think that is the use case for the adjoin. would this be a case of renaming and then removing the 's?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with *relabel* as following:  "relabel noun /^(.*)$/$1={pos}/" and then delete the POS node. You'll also have to change the Tregex to "(POS=postag < __=pos ) $- (NN < __=noun )".

Comment: Sorry, the correct relabel command is actually "relabel noun /^.*$/={noun}={pos}/".

Comment: This did not crash! and seems to be working, but it is not returning, could it somehow be recursive? This is a really great example of using the tree surgeon, can you recommend any resources for reference?

Comment: There is a link to Tsurgeon slides on that page, "the powerpoint slides for Tsurgeon"